# Issue with json message (data/processData)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm a beginner with jQuery and ajax. When I click on the add button, all the fields are empty. Then, I fill those fields in and when I click on the submit button, nothing happens. I don’t know what to do. Can anyone help me please?

When clicking on the add button:

```
$("#add").on("click", addSeries);

function addSeries() {

  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Serie/getAll", function(series) {
    series.length + 1;
    $("#txtSerieId").val(series.length + 1);
  });
}
```

When clicking on the submit button:

```
$("#submit").on("click", submit);

function submit() {

 var serieJson = '{"serie_id":' + $("#txtSerieId").val() + ',';
 serieJson += '"name" : "' + $("#txtName").val() + '",';
 serieJson += '"language_id" : "' + $("#txtLanguage_id").val() + '",';   
 serieJson += '"genre_id" : "' + $("#txtGenre").val() + '",';     
 serieJson += '"network_id" : "' + $("#txtNetwork").val() + '"';      
 serieJson += '}';

 $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/Series/add",
    data: serieJson,
    dataType: "json",
    processData:false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
 },
     success: function(data) {
        getAllSeries();
     }, error: function(err) { 
    }
});

}
```

Someone said me that the problem is here => data: serieJson. But I don't see what's wrong with my code.

Comment: have you checked your console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default submission of the form, so only the AJAX request is done. Use `Event.preventDefault()` for this.

Also, don't try to create JSON by concatenating strings. Create an array or object, then use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var serie = { 
        serie_id: $("#txtSerieId").val(),
        name: $("#txtName").val(),
        language_id: $("#txtLanguage_id").val(),
        genre_id: $("#txtGenre").val(),
        network_id: $("#txtNetwork").val()
    };
    var serieJson = JSON.stringify(serie);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/Series/add",
        data: serieJson,
        dataType: "json",
        processData:false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json"
    },
         success: function(data) {
            getAllSeries();
         }, error: function(err) { 
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :( I don't see any errors in my console